# Find elements in one list but not in other in exact order

Tags: c#, linq

I would assume there's a simple LINQ query to do this, I'm just not exactly sure how. Please see code snippet below, the comment explains what I'd like to do:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> peopleList1 = new List<Person>();
        peopleList1.Add(new Person() { ID = 1 });
        peopleList1.Add(new Person() { ID = 2 });
        peopleList1.Add(new Person() { ID = 3 });

        List<Person> peopleList2 = new List<Person>();
        peopleList2.Add(new Person() { ID = 2 });
        peopleList2.Add(new Person() { ID = 1 });
        peopleList2.Add(new Person() { ID = 4 });
        peopleList2.Add(new Person() { ID = 3 });
        peopleList2.Add(new Person() { ID = 5 });
    }
}
```

I would like to perform a LINQ query to give me all of the people in `peopleList1` that are not in `peopleList2` in the **exact same order**
 this example should give me three people:

> (ID = 1, 2 and 3)

I tried using

```
peopleList1.Except(peopleList2)
```

But this does not work on my scenario because I have to check for order also. List 1 should contain an element at the exact same position as list 2

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried Except but it does not check the order.

Comment: What do you mean by "exact position"??

Comment: btw  think about using something like a Hashset it has  method of finding elements depending of elements in the second set

Comment: My understanding so far ... there are two lists which contain same type of objects, the id is key between both. Do you want to check all the entries in one list against all entries in another or by "exact position" you mean, you want to check check item at position 1 in List 1 should be checked again "only" item at position 1 in List 2???

Comment: By exact position i mean the element at first position in list 1 should be at first position in list 2

Comment: @BhumikaSanghvi - your sample data will return an empty collection if that is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do

```
peopleList1.Where(x=>peopleList2.Count<peopleList1.IndexOf(x)+1||peopleList2[peopleList1.IndexOf(x)].ID!=x.ID).ToList()
```

Comment: I have edited the answer to cater for the clarification in the question i.e. exact same order

Comment: But this gives no result for OP's example.

Comment: If there would have been any matches, it would return a list of items that matched, otherwise the list would be empty. try changing the sample data to have a match, then test for the result.

Comment: e.g. Make the ID's of the first elements 1 and 2 respectively on both lists and test.

Comment: Did you test this with OP's data? Because when I tested this it doesn't give me three people (ID = 1, 2 and 3) as OP mentioned!

Comment: The current sample data as per the question and requirements will never match and give you any result, The result mentioned in the question was just an example of an expected result if there would have been any matches.

Comment: I've made a minor check on the list's length to avoid an IndexOutOfRangeException if list 2 will ever be shorter than list 1

Comment: poepleList1{"1","2","3"} and peopleList2 is {"1","4"} - output should be 2 and 3 present in 1 but missing from 2. I don't get this output with your solution

Comment: Sorry, I had overlooked the 'not'. I have updated the answer to show this unless the question meant something else.

Comment: It still doesnt give me 2 and 3 in output. Just 2

Comment: I've tried it and it gives me List<Person>(3) { Person { ID=1 }, Person { ID=2 }, Person { ID=3 } }.

Comment: But what if list 2 count is less than list 1. Then this doesnt work

Comment: this part in the code would take care of that 'peopleList2.Count>peopleList1.IndexOf(x)'

Comment: Yes i want something that would work irrespective of that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125992/discussion-between-bhumika-sanghvi-and-owuor).

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be what you want:

```
var result = peopleList1.Zip(peopleList2, (f, s) => f.ID != s.ID ? f.ID : 0)
                        .Where(c => c > 0).ToList();
```

The [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) checks the corresponding elements of `peopleList1` and `peopleList2`, and it is producing a sequence of the results which is elements that exist in `peopleList1` but not in `peopleList2` in exact same order.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET, the `List<T>` type is backed by an array, so the most efficient way to do this with LINQ would be to use the overload of `Select` that [also accesses the index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
peopleList1.Where((person, index) => peopleList2[index].Id != person.Id);
```

Comment: Yep, the original example has no elements that appear at the same index in both lists!

Comment: Did you test this with OP's data? Because when I tested this it doesn't give me three people (ID = 1, 2 and 3) as OP mentioned!

Comment: Ah, I missed out the 'not' part of his post! All that does is change the `==` to `!=` in the lambda

Comment: Also you need to change `peopleList2[index]` to `peopleList2[index].Id` so that this code works.

Comment: Done! I had just used an `int` list when testing and forgot to add it back on

Comment: Hey won't this break for two lists with different number of elements?

Comment: Yes i know it breaks.